# Sphinx latex_elements sphinxsetup not working correctly

Tags: python-sphinx

I'm creating a sphinx documentation with latex output for creating a pdf.

As part of this, I'm using the `conf.py` to modify certain elements of the output as below:

```
latex_elements = {
    "sphinxsetup": "shadowsize=0pt, shadowsep=4pt, VerbatimColor={rgb}{245, 246, 250}, noteborder=1pt, warningborder=1pt, dangerborder=1pt, noteBorderColor={rgb}{61, 133, 198}, warningBorderColor={rgb}{255, 153, 0}, dangerBorderColor={rgb}{255, 100, 97}"
}
```

This seems to impact some elements, e.g. `shadowsize` and `shadowsep` - but it does not seem to consistently impact my admonition boxes (note, warning, danger). The note and danger get no borders - while the warning gets a border, but in the incorrect color.

Am I using an incorrect syntax for this? I've tried to follow the official docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that changing from `rgb` to `RGB` solved this for me.